# Symfony, change database at runtime

Tags: php, database, symfony

I want to change the database at run-time.

**For example:**

In a web application a different database is created for each year (financial year) and a master table of years is in the main database.

After logging in, the user selects the year. Depending on the selected year, a different database is connected to at run-time.

Is that possible in Symfony?

Comment: Why is that data in a separate database? Sounds like bad design

Comment: It like a account software, so database need to be seperated for each financial year

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense to me. Relational data can be accessed by many properties but they don't need to reside in physically separate databases. In any case, have you read this ~ https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Thanks for advice, let me check

Comment: I've seen the same when looking at accounting department data. They prefer to have a set of data only from specific fiscal years. But this is usually only for accounting of AP/AR. Debts, Credit, Customer information, inventory, etc is available in the following year. So for general database design, as @Phil said it is highly discouraged from segregating your data into separate databases. Instead suggest looking into setting a rolling year into your display/models, and leave the data whole. Then ensure you have backups of that data from the previous fiscal year.

Comment: [Symfony dynamic DB connection](https://gist.github.com/samsch/9dd2cec7f21a3e879fd5) may be useful

Comment: Do you just need a connection or do you want an entity manager?  If there is a finite number of years then you can just define a manager for each year and then pull the desired one from the doctrine registry.